# passing a class method as opposed to a function in std::sort

Tags: c++, sorting, stdvector

Within a class, I am trying to sort a vector, by passing a method of the same class. But it gives errors at the time of compilation. Can anyone tell what the problem is? Thank you!

it gives the following error:
    argument of type `bool (Sorter::)(D&, D&)' does not match`bool (Sorter::*)(D&, D&)'

I have also tried using `sortBynumber(D const& d1, D const& d2)`

```
#include<vector>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

class D {
      public:                   
             int getNumber();            
             D(int val);
             ~D(){};
      private:
              int num;
};

D::D(int val){
         num = val;
         };

int D::getNumber(){
    return num;
};


class Sorter {
      public:                   
             void doSorting();  
             bool sortByNumber(D& d1, D& d2);
             std::vector<D> vec_D;          
             Sorter();
             ~Sorter(){};
      private:
              int num;
};

Sorter::Sorter(){                 
        int i;
        for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            vec_D.push_back(D(i));
           }
         };

bool Sorter::sortByNumber(D& d1, D& d2){
     return d1.getNumber() < d2.getNumber();
     };

void Sorter::doSorting(){
     std::sort(vec_D.begin(), vec_D.end(), this->sortByNumber);
     };




int main(){    
    Sorter s;
    s.doSorting();

    std::cout << "\nPress RETURN to continue...";
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why do you want `sortByNumber` as a member function? It can as well be a free function.

Comment: You don't have to be explicit about `D`'s destructor. You get that exact same code free of charge by the compiler. Less code, fewer bugs. ;) Also, I see `Sorter::vector` is public. Just an observation; that might not be what you meant to have. Another thing: If you know the vector's size, then you might as well specify it in the initialization list of `Sorter`, to avoid reallocation. Others have already talked about the importance of const-correctness, so you should take care of that. One last thing: in that for-loop you should have `i` a variable local to the loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make `Sorter::sortByNumber` static.  Since it doesn't reference any object members, you won't need to change anything else.

```
class Sorter {
public:                   
    static bool sortByNumber(const D& d1, const D& d2);
    ...
};

// Note out-of-class definition does not repeat static
bool Sorter::sortByNumber(const D& d1, const D& d2)
{
    ...
}
```

You should also use const references as `sortByNumber` should not be modifying the objects.

Comment: hmm, I tried this, but now it gives the following error: `cannot declare member function `static bool Sorter::sortByNumber(D&, D&)' to have static linkage `

Comment: @memC - don't use `static` before the definition itself.  Only use `static` before the declaration inside the `class`.

Comment: @Samuel: Thanks for the updates! I had earlier declared out-of-class definition as static. So made that change. But, changing `D&` to `const D&` is giving the following error: `passing `const D' as `this' argument of `int D::getNumber()' discards qualifiers `

Comment: @memc - you have two choices.  You can make `D::getNumber()` const (i.e. `int D::getNumber() const`) or you can have `sortByNumber` take the objects by value (i.e. `static bool sortByNumber(D d1, D d2)`)

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have a really good reason to do otherwise, just define `operator<` for the type of items you're sorting, and be done with it:

```
class D { 
    int val;
public:
    D(int init) : val(init) {}
    bool operator<(D const &other) { return val < other.val; }
};

class sorter { 
    std::vector<D> vec_D;
public:
    void doSorting() { std::sort(vec_d.begin(), vec_D.end()); }
};
```

The way you're writing your `sorter` class depends on knowing a *lot* about the internals of the `D` class, to the point that they're practically a single class (e.g., it looks like neither can do much of anything without the other).

At a guess, your `sorter` may be a somewhat stripped-down version of your real code. The `SortByNumber` makes it sound like the original code might support a number of different kinds of keys, something like:

```
class D { 
    std::string name;
    int height;
    int weight;
// ...
};
```

and you'd want to be able to sort `D` objects by name, height, or weight. In a case like that, the comparisons are really still related to the `D` class, so I'd probably put them into a common namespace:

```
namespace D { 
class D { 
    std::string name;
    int height;
    int weight;
public:
    friend class byWeight;
    friend class byHeight;
    friend class byName;
    // ...
};

struct byWeight { 
   bool operator()(D const &a, D const &b) { 
       return a.weight < b.weight;
   }
};

struct byHeight {
    bool operator()(D const &a, D const &b) { 
        return a.height < b.height;
    }
};

struct byName { 
    bool operator()(D const &a, D const &b) { 
        return a.name < b.name;
    }
};
}
```

Then sorting would look something like:

```
std::vector<D::D> vec_D;

// sort by height:
std::sort(vec_D.begin(), vec_D.end(), D::byHeight());

// sort by weight:
std::sort(vec_D.begin(), vec_D.end(), D::byWeight());

// sort by name:
std::sort(vec_D.begin(), vec_D.end(), D::byName());
```

Note that this does *not* use free functions. For this kind of purpose, a functor is generally preferable. I've also used a namespace to show the association between the object being sorted and the different ways of sorting it. You *could* make them nested classes instead, but I'd generally prefer the common namespace (keep coupling as loose as reasonable).

In any case, I would *not* give access to the raw data (even read-only access) via the object's public interface if it could be avoided (and in this case, it can be).

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason for `sortByNumber()` to be a member function. When it's a member function it gains access to things it doesn't need (and therefore shouldn't have access to). Either extract the method and refactor it into a function object:

```
struct sortByNumber {
    bool operator()(const D& d1, const D& d2) const {
        return d1.getNumber() < d2.getNumber();
    }
};
```

or make it a free function. Given the choice you should prefer a function object, because that makes it possible for the compiler to inline the code if it so chooses. Then, you can sort like so:

```
std::sort(vec_D.begin(), vec_D.end(), sortByNumber());
```

That said, you can get the code to compile as is like so, with `boost::bind()`:

```
std::sort(vec_D.begin(), vec_D.end(),
          boost::bind(&Sorter::sortByNumber, this, _1, _2));
```

You will need the boost libraries for that to work, and you will need to `#include <boost/bind.hpp>`.

Comment: Re: `bind1st` - You should try compiling these things. To begin with, there is no `mem_fun` for a method with two arguments. (But you could get things to compile with a more advanced `std::tr1::bind`.)

Comment: @UncleBens  :s oh the haste! Thanks for pointing this out. Yes, I should consult my compiler more often, and let my overconfidence have a rest every now and then.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason to make `sortByNumber` as a member function of class Sorter. You can do the sorting much more easily avoiding all the ugly bind code if you make it a free function. Also, you should use `const` wherever it is applicable in the code. Following is the example of doing it using free function:

First change the   `int getNumber()`  to const function as `int getNumber() const;`

Then write your free function `sortByNumber` again taking parameters by const reference.
 `bool sortByNumber(const D& d1, const D& d2);`

You can call `sort` as :
`std::sort(vec_D.begin(), vec_D.end(), sortByNumber);`

Comment: hi Naveen, This sorting is done only within this class. So I thought better put it within the class than being a free function.But seems like there is  quite a bit of overhead with making it a class function.

Comment: @memC that's not how you decide whether a function should be a member or not. When you make a function a member you essentially elevate its rights: you give it access to all protected and private members of the class. So class members are not "things that relate to the class" but rather "things that need access to the internals of the class". If the class needs some special service then you can create a free function that links statically. That is, the function will link locally to the class' compilation unit. You do that by placing the free function within an unnamed namespace.